# Making URLs in email work with x_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

So the consensus seems to be that in order to get URLs working in the emails your application sends, you have to set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`.

This is well and good if you're using `whatever_url` or `url_for`, but what if there's some helper or partial that you want to use to generate an email that uses `whatever_*path*`, e.g., `song_path(:song_slug => song, :artist_slug => song.artist)`?

How can I use such a helper in an email template without changing all these url-generating methods? Also, I thought using `whatever_path` instead of `whatever_url` was considered a best practice. If `whatever_path` is useless for email though, should I start using `whatever_url` everywhere in my application?

Answer (score 0):

No... Its ok and best practice to use asdasdad_path's, because they create relative paths.

asdasd_url's produces the absolute urls -> Your browser knows how to cope with relative paths, but how should that work in emails?

There is noch chance in your email to refer to a base-path(f.e. domain).

So you should use paths in your application and urls in email.